# Why the following two expressions have different results

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, fibonacci

```
fibs = 1:1:[x+y|x <- fibs, y <- tail fibs]
```

returns

> [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

```
fibs = 1:1:[x+y|(x, y) <- zip fibs (tail fibs)]
```

returns

> [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55...]

Comment: (I'm a rookie- -!).Because i think the first one does the same thing which extract pair from a fib seq and the tail.would u please explain more of the first one ?

Comment: oh i got it. thx!

Comment: good question. you could even write the second one equivalently as `fibs = 1:1: [ x+y | x <- fibs | y <- tail fibs]`. this uses an extension, ParallelListComp (for parallel list comprehensions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is evaluating the Cartesian product (i.e. every combination) of `fibs` and `tail fibs`, while the second is evaluating the pairwise pairing.

```
Prelude> [(x,y) | x <- [1,2,3], y <- [4,5,6]]
[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]

Prelude> [(x,y) | (x,y) <- [1,2,3] `zip` [4,5,6]]
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```